# How can I convert an HttpError into an Exception type?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a simple way to convert\cast `HttpError` to an `Exception`?

I am thinking of utilizing reflection to instantiate an exception based upon the content of `HttpError.Message` - is this the best way of accomplishing what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be very simple with reflection, you loose some elements including the stack trace though.

```
Type exceptionType = Type.GetType(httpError["ExceptionType"].ToString());
ConstructorInfo exceptionConstructor = exceptionType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
throw (Exception)exceptionConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { httpError["ExceptionMessage"] });
```

Comment: I tried this, but the exception that I needed to reconstruct was of type TypeInitializationException. This exception only has a constructor taking two arguments (message : string, and innerException : Exception), so in this case the answer is insufficient.

Comment: this does't handle InnerExceptions

Comment: I was just looking into this myself and, for now, I'm holding off on the idea until I understand the area better (today is the first day I've dealt with HttpError).  That said. . .I did some experiments with PowerShell where I  used Newtonsoft.Json to serialize an empty exception, tweaked the serialized exception with some string replacements (which could've come from HttpError) and deserialized the result with Newonsoft.Json.  For TypeInitializationException, I had to supply dummy values for the constructor parameters.  Not recommending it, just saying it seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

You can't Convert/Cast an `HttpError` to an `Exception`. Instead you can use the [HttpError.Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httperror.message%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to create a new Exception *(or your own custom exception)*

```
throw new Exception(HttpErrorObject.Message);
```

**EDIT:** If you want your own Custom exception then you can create a class like:

```
class MyHttpException : Exception
{
    public HttpError HttpErrorObject { get; set; }
    public MyHttpException(string Message, HttpError ErrorObject)
        : base(Message)
    {
        this.HttpErrorObject = ErrorObject;
    }
}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
HttpError httpErrorObject = new HttpError("404");
throw new MyHttpException(httpErrorObject.Message, httpErrorObject);
```

include the original error object, as told by [@Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034559/961113).

Comment: Unfortunately going this way original server side stack trace will be lost, if provided...

Comment: @DmitryNaumov, what "server side stack" it is an HttpError, that is being returned as exception. There is no original exception.

Comment: you didn't override ToString neither format Message to include "server stack" details into it when MyHttpException is logged somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You could always just make your own custom exception, and use the [HttpError.Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httperror.message%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property to get a reasonable message:

```
throw new YourHttpException(httpError.Message);
```

Including the `HttpError` could also be beneficial, as it is an entire dictionary of potential errors.